# uitableview not resizing with keyboard

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have created a view controller.
Setup a tableview that has a bunch of custom cells that contain text labels. When the keyboard comes up the frame of the tableview is not resizing automatically. Is there a checkbox in interface builder that I'm missing or something?

What settings should I check?

Comment: Is it UIViewController or UITableViewController? As you know tableView of a UITableViewController doesn't resize

Comment: Also even if you are using UIViewController, you must write resizing code when keyboard appears.

Comment: If that is so I will change it really quick to see what happens. You are correct. I am using a UIViewController.

Comment: That's it! Post it as an answer and I will mark it correct.

Comment: You can handle UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, UIKeyboardDidHideNotification for resizing the tableview appropriately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `UIViewController`, you must write resizing code when keyboard appears. You can handle `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` for resizing the tableview appropriately.

Comment: I used a UITableViewController and it works fine now...

Answer (score 11):

Add following keyboard notification event on your view controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

And resize your tableView's frame as per the keyboard notification:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize size = [[userInfo objectForKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, 
                              self.tableView.frame.origin.y, 
                              self.tableView.frame.size.width, 
                              self.tableView.frame.size.height - size.height);
    self.tableView.frame = frame;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize size = [[userInfo objectForKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, 
                                      self.tableView.frame.origin.y, 
                                      self.tableView.frame.size.width, 
                                      self.tableView.frame.size.height + size.height);
}
```

If you want to scroll up the tapp cell, do the following changes in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method:

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[textField superview] superview];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[tView indexPathForCell:cell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @matt's answer is correct. You should not be changing the tableView's frame when the keyboard appears.

Comment: This code didn't quite work for me.  First, the "keyboardWillHide" function still considered my onscreen keyboard to be 352 pixels high, instead of 0.  And secondly, on a Landscape iPad app, the "height" of the keyboard is actually stored in the "size.width" rather than "size.height" value.

Comment: The notification method should be:    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

Comment: Be sure to remove the observers to. Usually add in viewWillAppear and remove in viewWillDisappear