# Resize UITableView when I slide up a UIView, just like how it happens when the keyboard is shown

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am sliding up a `UIView` which has a `UIDatePicker` as a subview. This is added above my `UITableView`, but unfortunately some of the tableView rows are still under my `UIView`.

**UITableView is pushed up with keyboard:**

[image]

**UITableView is NOT pushed up with my view, covers up last few fields:**

[image]

Is it possible to resize the `UITableView` dynamically when I slide up my view, just like when the keyboard is shown when in a `tableView` and all the rows are still able to be seen?

**EDIT:**

Just found a great Apple example: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: You have to set the frame/contentOffset for the table view while adding the date picker. It wont automatically do this for picker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You could just go ahead and change the size of the UITableView dynamically as part of the animation that slides up the view. If you want to do what the UITableView actually does in response to the keyboard, leave its size alone and instead change its content inset and scroll indicator insets. See my answer here and the examples linked to:

[uitableview not resizing with keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632041/uitableview-not-resizing-with-keyboard/13632311#13632311)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was easier than I thought. In my case, when I touch a row, I want the picker to show and the `tableView` to change its height, so I use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^{

    self.pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-200, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.pickerView.frame.size.height);

    // shrink the table vertical size to make room for the date picker
    CGRect newFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    newFrame.size.height -= self.pickerView.frame.size.height;
    self.tableView.frame = newFrame;

} completion:nil];
```

Then when I click the done button, and want to return the `tableView` back to the full height and hide my datePicker, I use:

```
- (void)doneWithPicker:(BOOL)remove {

    CGRect newFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    newFrame.size.height += self.pickerView.frame.size.height;
    self.tableView.frame = newFrame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        self.pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+300, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.pickerView.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if (remove) {
            [self.pickerView removeFromSuperview];
            self.pickerView = nil;
        }
    }];

}
```

Also, when adding the `pickerView` as a subview, make sure to add it to the `window`:

```
[self.view.window addSubview:self.pickerView];
```